# Parallel threads, QT

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I'm newbie at QT and I've not a lot of expirience with working threads. 
I've readed many guides about threads and found that there are at least 3 ways to work with threds. I'm interested in one of them, there are my example: I've made class and I'm trying to use its function in thread.

.h

```
#ifndef IDENTIFICATOR_H_
#define IDENTIFICATOR_H_
#include <QtCore>
#include <QCoreApplication>

class identificator:public QObject {
Q_OBJECT
public:
    identificator(int i);
    virtual ~identificator();
private:
int id;
private slots:
void printID();
public:
void setID(int i);
int getID();
signals:
void finished();
};
```

.cpp

```
#include "identificator.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <QDebug>
identificator::identificator(int i) {
id=i;
}

identificator::~identificator() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}
void identificator::setID(int i)
{
id=i;
}
int identificator::getID()
{
return id;
}
void identificator::printID()
{
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
qDebug()<<" "<<this->getID()<<" "<<i<<" "<<this->thread();
    }emit finished();

}
```

and main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    printf("Hello\n");
    identificator *first=new identificator(0);
    identificator *second=new identificator(0);
    QThread *thread1=new QThread;
    QThread *thread2=new QThread;
    first->setID(3);
    second->setID(4);
    first->moveToThread(thread1);
    second->moveToThread(thread2);
    QObject::connect(thread1, SIGNAL(started()), first, SLOT(printID()));
    QObject::connect(thread2, SIGNAL(started()), second, SLOT(printID()));
    QObject::connect(first, SIGNAL(finished()), thread1, SLOT(quit()));
    QObject::connect(second, SIGNAL(finished()), thread2, SLOT(quit()));
    thread1->start();
    thread2->start();
    return a.exec();
}
```

I thought, that in console output there will be something like:
3
4
3
3
3
4
4
but I have only
4
4
4
4
4
4

I'm very need in Your help, thanks!

---

---

I have next output:

```
Hello
4 0 QThread(0x8053268)
3 0 QThread(0x8053250)
3 1 QThread(0x8053250)
3 2 QThread(0x8053250)
3 3 QThread(0x8053250)
3 4 QThread(0x8053250)
3 5 QThread(0x8053250)
3 6 QThread(0x8053250)
3 7 QThread(0x8053250)
3 8 QThread(0x8053250)
3 9 QThread(0x8053250)
4 1 QThread(0x8053268)
4 2 QThread(0x8053268)
4 3 QThread(0x8053268)
4 4 QThread(0x8053268)
4 5 QThread(0x8053268)
4 6 QThread(0x8053268)
4 7 QThread(0x8053268)
4 8 QThread(0x8053268)
4 9 QThread(0x8053268)
```

Comment: Your code *should* work. Can you give the full output of your program? It matters to know if you have 10 4s of 20 4s.

Comment: I have added program output to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output is correct, and your program works correctly

- thread1 start and is preempted before printing anything
- thread2 start, output 4, is interrupted
- thread1 has the processor, output 3 ten times, till it emit finished
- thread2 has the processor again and can output 4 nine times, till it emit finished

Couple of things:

- The number of iteration in printID is too small to see real
  preemption between both threads (even if in this case t2 was interrupted once)
- **qDebug doesn't flush the output**. it just put a newline at the end. Which means you could miss some output lines on the  console. It is totally possible to see only 1 value printed.
- **You cannot expect a specific output from that code**. Any permutation  of ten 3 and ten 4 may occur.
- It seems like qdebug has some lock, otherwise you could see even mangled output because you don't flush.

Try the same exercise with more than 10 iterations, no flushing, no output sync

```
std::cout <<" "<<this->getID()<<" "<<i<<" "<<this->thread() << "\n";
```

and flushing (no need to sync)

```
std::cout <<" "<<this->getID()<<" "<<i<<" "<<this->thread() << std::endl;
```

Comment: ok, I changed the number of function iteration from 10 to 100, and I see that in output number 4 appear first, then 3. But threads does not work parallel, they work after each other.

Comment: I understand, that there were not specific output, but I'm trying to check thath threads work parallel....how can I do that, if qDebug is not correct thing for checking?

Comment: First, you cannot control thread execution up to the point to force them to run in parallel. This is done by the operating system and depends on many things: hardware (if you do not have a multi core CPU they will never run in parallel), system workload (other processes), etc. You could set each thread to run on a different core by setting their affinity, but there is still no guarantee.

Comment: @BenjaminT was typing it at the moment.

Comment: Second point, QDebug is indeed not the right tool for checking if threads are running in parallel, because as stated by @UmNyobe, there is some kind of locking to prevent them to access to the output at the same time. this locking mechanism will prevent you from seeing any effect of having parallel threads.

To see if your thread are working in parallel, replace `qDebug()` by `std::cout`, do not flush (use `\n` instead of `std::endl`, like in @UmNyobe answer), and add a long string to the output. The thread outputs should get mixed when they try to output at the same time.

Comment: @BenjaminT `qDebug` uses a simple mutex to avoid data races, the same as `std::cout` does in C++11 (!!). There's no magic to it. If you have a thread that does very little work, as is the case here, you won't be able to observe any effects of concurrency with any sort of reliability.

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/4btvaHr6) - the first variant of output; [link](http://pastebin.com/bAnBFpig) - the second variant of output ; there is no parallel work, as I see.

Comment: So, I can't understand, why in this case [link](http://www.evileg.ru/baza-znanij/qt/qthread-sozdanie-potokov-v-qt.html) threads are working parallel. I see, that there is different approach, but....

Answer (score 1):

The main program should wait the threads. Call the wait function before exiting.

```
thread1.wait();
thread2.wait();
```

Comment: I have added this functions, but I still have troubles....It does not change situation...

Comment: from the output you pasted i see mixed 3s and 4s so what is the problem? Also in the constructor you should add the parent widget and pass the parent when creating the class because it results in better memory management, i think

Answer (score 1):

> I thought, that in console output there will be something like: 3 4 3 3 3 4 4 but I have only 4 4 4 4 4 4

You thought wrong. You should **never** assume that threads that execute concurrently do so in any particular way. The only way to observe concurrency consistently is to use synchronization primitives. A way to observe it in a less reliable way is to do work that takes significant time. Your threads lead very short lives and do very little work. In the time before `thread1->start()` and `thread2->start()`, the first thread might be done with its work, or it might not have executed any code yet. In fact, thread2 might finish before thread1 has done anything.

The semantics of `QThread::start()` are **not** "wait until my code in the thread has done something". They are, quite simply, "ensure that the thread will be running at some unspecified point in the future".

Answer (score -1):

create the object of class properly for identifier or call constructor of identifier properly. constructor expecting the value so make it as a default constructor or you can do like this
identificator *first=new identificator(5);

Comment: I'm sorry for my inattention, I have changed the main.cpp, but program doesn't still work properly....